# IntelliJ IDEA complex code cleanup like Resharper?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resharper

Is there anything similar to [Code Cleanup](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Reference__Code_Cleanup.html) from Resharper in IntelliJ IDEA? Something that runs all the different optimizations on your code. (Switching from C# to Java)

[image: Code Cleanup Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old [IntelliJ IDEA 14 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP) there is automatic ["Code cleanup"](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/try-intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1283-4-with-code-cleanup-android-studio-beta-features-and-more/) feature. It's located in *Analyse* → *Code Cleanup* menu.

In the latest versions of IDEA (such as 2016) there is *Analyse* → [*Inspect Code*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-inspection.html) and *Code* → [*Optimize Imports*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/optimizing-imports.html) features.

Comment: It's the same as [2016.3](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2016.3+EAP)?

Comment: @J2ghz 2016.3 is the latest. I've update my answer to provide more info about it.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij can reformat your code:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/reformatting-source-code.html

For more advanced/customized formatting look here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-code-style.html

Comment: That fixes indentation and whitespace. I want something that also sorts methods, remove unused imports etc.